# What would be the mapping for the vim to insert mode from normal on left-click of mouse?

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm new to vim, I'm trying to map the left-click of the mouse to change the mode of vim especially on left-click to insert mode. This looks like wrong mapping `imap <LeftMouse>i` in my .vimrc. I'm thankful if you could help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From insert mode to normal mode:

```
inoremap <leftmouse> <esc>
```

From normal mode to insert mode:

```
nnoremap <leftmouse> i
```

Comment: The answer is exact what I looking for you're awesome :), I got the warning after mapping  `vim cannot make changes modifiable is off`.  I figured it out and set the modifiable in my .vimrc

Answer (score 0):

You already enabled the mouse support?

```
set mouse=a
```

also the basic syntax is: {cmd} {attr} {lhs} {rhs} where {cmd} is one of the map (imap, vmap etc); {attr} which is more optional with options like , ; {lhs} which means left hand side and this contains the keys that you will use in your new shortcut and finally {rhs} which contains the keys you like to be executed with your new shortcut.

Comment: Yes, I enabled  sorry I forgot to mention.

Comment: Okay. May the syntax explanation helps you a bit. Here is a example: map! <F6> <C-R>=strftime('%c')<CR>

Comment: This is not the exact answer to my question.